# How to fetch records using predicate from A having relationship with A<-->B<-->C with coredata

Tags: xcode, core-data, fetch, using, predicate

I have three entities A,B,C.
EntityA:
Properties:
Id,Name
Relationships:
ABRelation(A-->>B)

EntityB:
Properties:
Id,Name
Relationships:
BARelation(B-->A)
BCRelation(B-->>C)

EntityC:
RoleId
CBRelation(C-->>B)

Now I need to fetch records from Entity A having some RoleId = 23 which is contain in C.

Could you please help me quickly.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name,
FROM EntityA a INNER JOIN EntityB b
   ON a.Id= b.EntityA_Id(foriegn key) JOIN EntityC as c
   ON b.EntityC_Id(foriegn key) = c.Id
WHERE c.RoleId=23
```

Comment: Could you please provide how to write predicate using coredata for IOS?

Comment: you should tag this question for ios developers to help you . I am sorry I am not one of them .